# Weird message Visual Studio C++ 2022

Tags: visual-c++

Can anyone explain to me this? I get weird message in my program, see the images below:

[image]

and also this:

[image]

Comment: You are using some library named "harfbuzz", and you use it incorrectly in some way.

Comment: What about the peiran thing?

Comment: No idea. For all I know, it's something your code (not shown) prints.

Comment: Oh, I use SDL, is this related?

Comment: Peiran message may be related to this: https://community.intel.com/t5/Developing-Games-on-Intel/igdumdim64-dll-is-spamming-Windows-log-via-OutputDebugString/m-p/1422306